# MySQL database clustering - Problems connecting SQL node (mysqld) to other nodes

Tags: database, config, mysql

I'm trying to do MySQL database clustering on 5 computers: 1 for management node (ndb_mgmd), 2 for data node (ndbd), and 2 for SQL node (mysqld). I could get the management node and data nodes running but I couldn't run the SQL node.

This is the error message:
**[ERROR] Can't find messagefile 'C:\mysql\cluster\share\errmsg.sys'**

and this is the command that I used to run the SQL node:
**start /B C:\mysql\cluster\bin\mysqld --defaults-file=conf\my.101.cnf**
**start /B C:\mysql\cluster\bin\mysqld --defaults-file=conf\my.102.cnf**

This is the **config.ini** that I'm using for management node:

```
    [ndbd default]
    noofreplicas=2
    datadir=C:\MySQL_Cluster\My_Cluster\data

    [ndbd]
    hostname=localhost
    NodeId=2

    [ndbd]
    hostname=localhost
    NodeId=3

    [ndb_mgmd]
    NodeId=1
    hostname=localhost

    [mysqld]
    NodeId=101
    hostname=localhost

    [mysqld]
    NodeId=102
    hostname=localhost
```

**my.101.cnf** file contains:

```
    [mysqld]
    ndb-nodeid=101
    ndbcluster
    datadir=C:\MySQL_Cluster\My_Cluster\data\mysqld1
    port=3306
```

**and my.102.cnf** contains:

```
    [mysqld]
    ndb-nodeid=102
    ndbcluster
    datadir=C:\MySQL_Cluster\My_Cluster\data\mysqld2
    port=3307
```

Answer (score 0):

In your .cnf files make sure that you define the basedir (where the MySQL Cluster software is installed). On Windows the syntax for defining the path is a little different - e.g. basedir=c:\\Users\\user1\\mysqlc

Andrew.